# Cannot login to any Magento store admin and frontend only for my system

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I am not able to login to any magento store (even the demo magento store hosted on magento website). It was working fine a few days ago but now I am not able to login and my work is pending. I even tried to clear my cache bt nothing happend. Can you all help ??

Comment: This is not  a programming question so it's off-topic here on SO. Consider asking on the Magento Forum

Comment: What's happening, when you try to login? Blank page? Error messages? Do you see the same login form again without an error message? Check the log files. It's hard to help you without any informations.

Comment: @MartinRothenberger - The error that I face is that the url shows that it is into the admin panel bt the screen shows the login panel again. I dont see any error.. I can work on other pc's bt not on mine's

Comment: That's sound like a problem connectiong to SSL/HTTPS, or a session caching problem. Do you use memcache for your Sessions? Did you configure a secure amdin url? HTTPS?

Comment: Definitely not a programming question and only affects your PC?.. definitely too localized as well. This is not a good topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything in `var/session` and try to login again.

Answer (score 0):

What Browser are you using? When I tried to log in with Chrome, it didn't work. Then I tried logging in on Opera and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the following is true

> even the demo magento store hosted on magento website

then it means the problem is localized to your computer.  That said, if this bit is accurate

> I dont see any error

then it means your computer and/or web browser can't set any cookies.  Magento (like 99% of modern web applications) uses a cookie based session implementation, and Magento relies on sessions to surface error messages to end users.  Check your browsers security settings, or switch to a different browser.  If that doesn't work you'll need to figure out why your computer can't set cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory.

Find the code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath(),
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

and replace with

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath()
//$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
//$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
//$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

After this save the file. and Clear you all cache file from var->cache And try to login into the admin.

I think it will work now.
thanks

Comment: Never ever touch the core code! You won't be able to update anymore and that's a really bad coding behaviour.

Comment: you can overwrite the core code by taking copy directory to local directory.

Comment: Sure you can,... but that isn't what you recommended to do.